# Pandas: Improve a high cost double looping algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

Having a Pandas dataframe like:

|  | groupId | intTime | stringCol | relationId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15939901 | 20230711092405 | Some text 0 | 7871917237227544415 |
| 1 | 15937877 | 20230801172006 | Some text similar to text 0 | 1797663680516522920 |
| 2 | 15937468 | 20230711092405 | Some text 2 | 15107665621016585700 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15998 | 15937468 | 20230807141205 | Some text 1554 | 15473262095727381524 |
| 15999 | 15937877 | 20230803100127 | Some text similar to text 0 | 2215491974943179763 |
| 16000 | 15937468 | 20230709092403 | Some text 1598 | 15107665621016585700 |

I want to compare each element in the "string_col" column with the other elements below the same column, and if the element belongs to the same "groupId" and if the text is similar update the "retationId" to the same value. So,the result would be:

|  | groupId | intTime | stringCol | relationId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15939901 | 20230711092405 | Some text 0 | 7871917237227544415 |
| 1 | 15937877 | 20230801172006 | Some text 1 | 1797663680516522920 |
| 2 | 15937468 | 20230711092405 | Some text 2 | 15107665621016585700 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 15998 | 15937468 | 20230807141205 | Some text 1554 | 15473262095727381524 |
| 15999 | 15937877 | 20230803100127 | Some text similar to text 1 | **1797663680516522920** |
| 16000 | 15937468 | 20230709092403 | Some text 1598 | 15107665621016585700 |

My approach has been the following: (comparator calculates the Levenshtein Distance and returns True if is relatively similar, otherwise False)

```
for i in df.index:
  for j in range(i+1, len(df)):
    if (df['groupId'].loc[i] == df['groupId'].loc[j]) and (comparator(df['stringCol'].loc[i], df['stringCol'].loc[j])):
        df.loc[j, 'relationId'] = df['relationId'].loc[i]
```

This algorithm has a very high time cost. Is there some internal Pandas function to achieve the same result more efficiently?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'groupId': [15939901, 15937877, 15937468, 15937468, 15937877, 15937468],
    'intTime': [20230711092405, 20230801172006, 20230711092405, 20230807141205, 20230803100127, 20230709092403],
    'stringCol': ['Some text 0', 'Some text similar to text 0', 'Some text 2', 'Some text 1554', 'Some text similar to text 0', 'Some text 1598'],
    'relationId': [7871917237227544415, 1797663680516522920, 15107665621016585700, 15473262095727381524, 2215491974943179763, 15107665621016585700]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Function to compare strings
def comparator(str1, str2):
    return str1 == str2  # Customize your comparator logic here

# Create a new DataFrame with unique group-string pairs and their corresponding relationId
unique_pairs = df[['groupId', 'stringCol', 'relationId']].drop_duplicates()

# Merge the unique pairs DataFrame with itself on groupId and stringCol
merged = unique_pairs.merge(unique_pairs, on=['groupId', 'stringCol'], suffixes=('', '_new'))

# Filter out the self-merges and keep the relevant columns
filtered_merged = merged[merged.index != merged.index_new][['groupId', 'stringCol', 'relationId']]

# Update the original DataFrame with the updated relationIds
updated_df = df.merge(filtered_merged, on=['groupId', 'stringCol'], how='left', suffixes=('', '_new'))
updated_df['relationId'] = updated_df['relationId_new'].fillna(updated_df['relationId'])
updated_df.drop(columns=['relationId_new'], inplace=True)

print(updated_df)
```